# Asking for training during new-hire probation period

Tags: new-job, training

I am working in a company for about a month. But I changed my field a bit and I want to learn the unknown stuff. There is a training coming in the next month which I think will be useful for my job. But it is coming on working days. If I miss the class I would have to wait for 4-5 months for the next class offering.

I am in a dilemma whether to ask the employer for the leave or put two days paid leave and go for the training. I am not allowed annual leave since I am in my new employee probation period.

Is it okay to ask for the training before confirmation..?

Comment: If you represented yourself as an expert in the field in which you want training, it might be a problem.  Otherwise, I'm in the "the worst they can do is say 'No'" crowd.

Comment: Would they see this skill as essential, relevant, nice-to-have or irrelevant to your current job function? what level do they expect you to currently have in that skill?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the training is indeed beneficial for your job, I would say go ahead and ask for it! If it has (positive) influence in how you can do your job, your employer wil benefit from it, too! Also, it shows your employer that you're eager to learn and you are happy to gather new knowledge.

However, keep in mind that it really has to be beneficial for your job. If it's only partly beneficial, your employer will think that you are jumping (too) quickly into unrelated areas which can be seen as a bad thing.

Comment: I like this answer, but I'd add the twist - ask your boss what he thinks of the course.  After all - you're new, he probably does know better, he may even know folks that have taken it.  Then (if he's favorable to it) ask about whether you can be paid as a regular work day for taking it.  Most knowledge-work positions have paid training days factored into the schedule, and usually there are work subsidies for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're a new person, you may not want to jump onto the new, fancy stuff right away, and instead get involved and absorbed into the culture and needs of the workplace.  It may be that the training would be beneficial to the company, but you wouldn't have a good grasp of what's beneficial until you've been around for at least half a year.

Answer (score 3):

If you can make a good case for your taking the training being beneficial to the employer, go ahead and ask.  Your case needs to be solid.

Remember: If you don't ask, you aren't giving them the chance to say "Yes".  Note that this has applications outside of work...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the training is beneficial to your job performance you need to have a conversation about training for several reasons:

- You need to understand if the company ever pays for a training class. Do they provide the money for the class? Do they pay for the hours? Or even better, they do both.
- Some companies provide a maximum amount of money for training per employee each year. This pays for the class fee, but does not pay for the hours. Therefore the employee has to makeup the time, take vacation, or take the training online. The employee still needs to ask permission from a supervisor, but there is money in the budget.
- Some companies provide a maximum amount of money for tuition reimbursement for classes taken at a college/university for the purposes of getting a degree, or an additional degree. In the US there are some IRS regulations regarding this process. The company needs to approve the course of study. Some companies add a requirement that if you leave the company too soon, they want to be reimbursed for the money they paid you.
- Some companies have access to online training programs. These can be very limited to required time card and safety training, or very broad to include technical subjects, and management training.

The answers to these issues may be found in the HR documents, or the annual benefits package. You may discover that some of these educational benefits are not available to you during this initial period with the company, but you need to do your research. And if you can't find the information, or if you can't understand the procedures about the company, then ask.